# variable transliteration (powershell)

Tags: powershell, foreach, translation, translate

There is a problem that I could not solve quickly.
The point is to iterate over all matches from two tables with letters.
**for example my script**

```
function global:TranslitToLAT {
    param([string]$inString)
    $Translit_To_LAT = @{
        [char]'а' = "a"
        [char]'А' = "a"
        [char]'б' = "b"
        [char]'Б' = "b"
        [char]'в' = "v"
        [char]'В' = "v"
        [char]'г' = "g"
        [char]'Г' = "g"
        [char]'д' = "d"
        [char]'Д' = "d"
        [char]'е' = "e"
        [char]'Е' = "e"
        [char]'ё' = "e"
        [char]'Ё' = "e"
        [char]'ж' = "zh"
        [char]'Ж' = "zh"
        [char]'з' = "z"
        [char]'З' = "z"
        [char]'и' = "i"
        [char]'И' = "i"
        [char]'й' = "y"
        [char]'Й' = "y"
        [char]'к' = "k"
        [char]'К' = "k"
        [char]'л' = "l"
        [char]'Л' = "l"
        [char]'м' = "m"
        [char]'М' = "m"
        [char]'н' = "n"
        [char]'Н' = "n"
        [char]'о' = "o"
        [char]'О' = "o"
        [char]'п' = "p"
        [char]'П' = "p"
        [char]'р' = "r"
        [char]'Р' = "r"
        [char]'с' = "s"
        [char]'С' = "s"
        [char]'т' = "t"
        [char]'Т' = "t"
        [char]'у' = "u"
        [char]'У' = "u"
        [char]'ф' = "f"
        [char]'Ф' = "f"
        [char]'х' = "h"
        [char]'Х' = "h"
        [char]'ц' = "ts"
        [char]'Ц' = "ts"
        [char]'ч' = "ch"
        [char]'Ч' = "ch"
        [char]'ш' = "sh"
        [char]'Ш' = "sh"
        [char]'щ' = "sch"
        [char]'Щ' = "sch"
        [char]'ъ' = "" # "``"
        [char]'Ъ' = "" # "``"
        [char]'ы' = "y" # "y`"
        [char]'Ы' = "y" # "Y`"
        [char]'ь' = "" # "`"
        [char]'Ь' = "" # "`"
        [char]'э' = "e" # "e`"
        [char]'Э' = "e" # "E`"
        [char]'ю' = "yu"
        [char]'Ю' = "yu"
        [char]'я' = "ya"
        [char]'Я' = "ya"
        [char]' ' = "_"
    }
    $outChars = ""
    $TwoLetter_To_LAT = @{
        [string]'ъи' = 'yi'
        [string]'ьи' = 'yi'
        [string]'ье' = 'ye'
        [string]'ъe' = 'ye'
        [string]'ий' = 'ii'
        [string]'кс' = 'x'
        [string]'ц' = 'c'
    }

    $chars = $inString.ToCharArray();
    $outChars1 = $outChars
    foreach ($char in $chars) {
    $outChars1 += $Translit_To_LAT[$char]

    $outChars11 = Write-Output $outChars1 `n
    
    }
    
    

    $TwoLetter_To_LAT.GetEnumerator().name | % {
        $inString = $inString.Replace($_, $TwoLetter_To_LAT.Item($_))
    }
    $outChars2 = $outChars
    foreach ($c in $inChars = $inString.ToCharArray()) {
        if ($Translit_To_LAT[$c] -ne $Null )
        { $outChars2 += $Translit_To_LAT[$c] }
        else
        { $outChars2 += $c }
    $outChars22 = Write-Output $outChars2 `n
    }
    
    
    $outChars3 = $outChars11 + $outChars22

    Write-Output $outChars3
}

$text = Read-Host "Second name"
$log = TranslitToLAT $text | select $log > c:\users.txt
$log
```

It works partially. When entering a surname in Russian, where there are two matches from the second table, I get the total from the first table and from the second. And I should get 4 transliteration options!
I will be happy with an example of how to make the loop go through the table over and over again.

Comment: Can you provide a sample input string for which the problem occurs?

Comment: No problem)) enter - Алексий or Зелекский
there will be only two options, but there should be four.

Comment: Can you confirm what output are you're currently getting and what you're expecting for ```Алексий``` and ```Зелекский``` so that we can try to reproduce locally?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewording it a bit, I think the question you're asking is "given a source string `$inString` and a list of substitutions `$Translit_To_LAT`, return a list of all possible combinations of substitutions applied to the source string".

For example, I'm assuming that your example - `Алексий` - would give the 4 substitutions below:

```
1. А-л-е-к-с-и-й -> a-l-e-k-s-i-y 
2. А-л-е-к-с-ий  -> a-l-e-k-s-ii
3. А-л-е-кс-и-й  -> a-l-e-x-i-y
4. А-л-е-кс-ий   -> a-l-e-x-ii
```

There's a few things to watch out for though based on your substitution list:

- It's case-sensitive, with potentially different substitutions for e.g. `б` and `Б`
- Some substitutions have more than one character in the replacement text - e.g. `ж` => `"zh"`
- Some substitutions have multiple replacement options - e.g. `ц` => `c` *and* `ts`
- Some substitutions match more than one source character - e.g. `ъи` => `yi`
- There's sometimes multiple possible substitutions for the same sequence of characters - e.g. `ий` can be two separate substitutions ("`и` => `i` and `й` => `y`) or a separate "composite" substitution (`ий` => `ii`)

I've rewritten your code as a recursive function which basically does the following:

- If the input string is empty, just return an empty string
- Otherwise, enumerate all the substitutions that can be applied at the start of the string, and "multiply" them with the result of a recursive call with the tail of the string

Here's the code:

```
function Get-Transliteration
{
    param(
        [string] $InputString
    )

    $lookups = [ordered] @{
        # single character substitutions
        # (we need to use the [char] cast to force case sensitivity for keys)
        [char] "а" = @( "a" )
        [char] "А" = @( "a" )
        [char] "б" = @( "b" )
        [char] "Б" = @( "b" )
        [char] "в" = @( "v" )
        [char] "В" = @( "v" )
        [char] "г" = @( "g" )
        [char] "Г" = @( "g" )
        [char] "д" = @( "d" )
        [char] "Д" = @( "d" )
        [char] "е" = @( "e" )
        [char] "Е" = @( "e" )
        [char] "ё" = @( "e" )
        [char] "Ё" = @( "e" )
        [char] "ж" = @( "zh" )
        [char] "Ж" = @( "zh" )
        [char] "з" = @( "z" )
        [char] "З" = @( "z" )
        [char] "и" = @( "i" )
        [char] "И" = @( "i" )
        [char] "й" = @( "y" )
        [char] "Й" = @( "y" )
        [char] "к" = @( "k" )
        [char] "К" = @( "k" )
        [char] "л" = @( "l" )
        [char] "Л" = @( "l" )
        [char] "м" = @( "m" )
        [char] "М" = @( "m" )
        [char] "н" = @( "n" )
        [char] "Н" = @( "n" )
        [char] "о" = @( "o" )
        [char] "О" = @( "o" )
        [char] "п" = @( "p" )
        [char] "П" = @( "p" )
        [char] "р" = @( "r" )
        [char] "Р" = @( "r" )
        [char] "с" = @( "s" )
        [char] "С" = @( "s" )
        [char] "т" = @( "t" )
        [char] "Т" = @( "t" )
        [char] "у" = @( "u" )
        [char] "У" = @( "u" )
        [char] "ф" = @( "f" )
        [char] "Ф" = @( "f" )
        [char] "х" = @( "h" )
        [char] "Х" = @( "h" )
        [char] "ц" = @( "c", "ts")
        [char] "Ц" = @( "ts" )
        [char] "ч" = @( "ch" )
        [char] "Ч" = @( "ch" )
        [char] "ш" = @( "sh" )
        [char] "Ш" = @( "sh" )
        [char] "щ" = @( "sch" )
        [char] "Щ" = @( "sch" )
        [char] "ъ" = @( "" )
        [char] "Ъ" = @( "" )
        [char] "ы" = @( "y" )
        [char] "Ы" = @( "y" )
        [char] "ь" = @( "" )
        [char] "Ь" = @( "" )
        [char] "э" = @( "e" )
        [char] "Э" = @( "e" )
        [char] "ю" = @( "yu" )
        [char] "Ю" = @( "yu" )
        [char] "я" = @( "ya" )
        [char] "Я" = @( "ya" )
        [char] " " = @( "_" )
        # multi-character substitutions
        [string] "ъи" = @( "yi" )
        [string] "ьи" = @( "yi" )
        [string] "ье" = @( "ye" )
        [string] "ъe" = @( "ye" )
        [string] "ий" = @( "ii" )
        [string] "кс" = @( "x" )
    }

    # if the input is empty then there's no work to do,
    # so just return an empty string
    if( [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($InputString) )
    {
        return [string]::Empty;
    }

    # find all the lookups that can be applied at the start of the string
    $keys = @( $lookups.Keys | where-object { $InputString.StartsWith($_) } );

    # if there are no lookups found at the start of the string we'll keep
    # the first character as-is and prefix it to all the transliterations
    # for the remainder of the string
    if( $keys.Length -eq 0 )
    {
        $results = @();
        $head    = $InputString[0];
        $rest    = $InputString.Substring(1);
        $tails   = Get-Transliteration -InputString $rest;
        foreach( $tail in $tails )
        {
            $results += $head + $tail;
        }
        return $results;
    }

    # if we found any lookups at the start of the string we need to "multiply"
    # them with all the transliterations for the remainder of the string
    $results = @();
    foreach( $key in $keys )
    {
        if( $InputString.StartsWith($key) )
        {
            $heads = $lookups[$key];
            $rest  = $InputString.Substring(([string] $key).Length);
            $tails = Get-Transliteration -InputString $rest;
            foreach( $head in $heads )
            {
                foreach( $tail in $tails )
                {
                    $results += $head + $tail;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    return $results;

}
```

And here's some examples:

```bsh
# no substitutions to apply
PS> Get-Transliteration "abc"
abc

# single substitution with multiple characters in the replacement text
PS> Get-Transliteration "[ж]"
[zh]

# multiple replacement options for a single match
PS> Get-Transliteration "[ц]"
[c]
[ts]

# replace multiple source characters for a single match
PS> Get-Transliteration "[ъи]"
[i]
[yi]

# replace multiple possible options
PS> Get-Transliteration "[кс]-[ий]"
[ks]-[iy]
[ks]-[ii]
[x]-[iy]
[x]-[ii]

# original sample - "Алексий"
PS> Get-Transliteration "Алексий"
aleksiy
aleksii
alexiy
alexii

# original sample - "Зелекский"
PS> Get-Transliteration "Зелекский"
zelekskiy
zelekskii
zelexkiy
zelexkii
```

Looking at the wikipedia page here - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BGN/PCGN_romanization_of_Russian - I think the transliteration rules are a bit more complicated than this function can handle, but hopefully it's a start...

Comment: Thank you very much!
Regarding the wiki, you are right, but idealization of this process is not critical for me.