# PowerShell - Complex replacement in a string

Tags: powershell

I have a very complex question regarding a complex replacement in a file name, I will try to explain it

I am reading a file name that has an agreed signs in our company such as: %20 , _ that representing
a different signs.

```
'%20' represent a space 
'_' represent '/'
```

According to those signs I am searching the file in the right place in the TFS and its working fine
when '*' is really represent '/' but what happen when '*' is part of a name?

Lets see an easy example while there is only one '_' in the file name mail_sp.sql
It could be converted to : mail/sp.sql or mail_sp.sql
Here is the code I wrote (I don't know if its working or not, feel free to correct me please)

CheckFileExistsTfs is a function that return True or False depend if the file exist in the TFS

```
function CheckFileExistsTfs {
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $tfsFilePath,
        [string] $userName,
        [string] $userPassword,
        [string] $userDomain
    )

    Add-Type -AssemblyName 'System.Net.Http'

    $clientHandler = New-Object System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler

    if ($userName) {
        $clientHandler.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($userName, $userPassword, $userDomain)
    }
    else {
        $clientHandler.UseDefaultCredentials = 1
    }
    
    $client = New-Object System.Net.Http.HttpClient($clientHandler)

    $tfsBranchPath = "https://tfs.bandit.com/DefaultCollection/Idu Client-Server/_apis/tfvc/items?scopePath=$tfsFilePath"

    #Write-Host "Sending get request (items api) to url: " $tfsBranchPath
    $response = $client.GetAsync($tfsBranchPath).Result
    $contentObjects = $response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result | ConvertFrom-Json

    $exists = $contentObjects.count -eq 1
    
    $fileSize = 0
    
    if ($exists) {
        $fileSize = $contentObjects.value[0].size / 1024
    }   

    $result = [PSCustomObject]@{
        FileExists      = $exists
        FileSizeInBytes = $fileSize
    }

    return $result
}
```

$PatchBranch is the path in the TFS like $/Idu Client-Server/Branches/V6.4/Releases/v8.6.24-CU/Database/

```
$sql = mail_sp.sql
$newname = $sql.Name.Replace('%20', ' ').replace('_', '/')
$filePathInTfs = $PatchBranch + $new
$fileExist = CheckFileExistsTfs $filePathInTfs

if ($fileExist)
{ Write-Host "TFS file existance is: [$fileExist] by path [$filePathInTfs]" }
                         
elseif (!$fileExist) {
    $new = $sql.Name.Replace('%20', ' ')
    $filePathInTfs = $PatchBranch + $new
    $fileExist = CheckFileExistsTfs $filePathInTfs

    if ($fileExist) 
    { Write-Host "TFS file existance is: [$fileExist] by path [$filePathInTfs]" }

}
else { Write-Host "TFS file not exist : [$fileExist] by path [$filePathInTfs] " }
```

**But** what if the name is mail_sp_sp.sql? or even more '_'  will be many combinations:

```
mail/sp_sp.sql
mail/sp/sql.sql
mail_sp/sql.sql
mail_sp_sql.sql
mail/sp_sql.sql
```

**Additional example:**

`AD%20mail_sp.sql` should be converted to:

```
  AD mail_sp.sql
  AD mail/sp.sql
```

The goal is to check each combination and if one of them is true stop the iteration and display a message, only when all the tries failed then return false or give a proper message.

What I am asking is to check if the first code is working (when there is only one '_') and help to check the complex combinations
Thanks

Comment: To paraphrase your question just so I understand, you have a file path which you've encoded by replacing ```/``` with ```_``` and [space] with ```%20```. You want to reverse the encoding to get back to the original file path, but because your encoding is ambiguous (i.e. ```_``` in your encoded string could mean ```/``` or ```_``` in the original file path) you need to generate all possible original values and then find the one that exists on your file system?

Comment: Could you show us your `CheckFileExistsTfs` ? I might be possible to have that function look for a regex pattern instead of trying out many combinations. It may then either return $null, a single file path or multiple possible files. Something like `$pattern = $sql.Name.Replace('%20', ' ').Replace("_", '[_/]') + '$'` and then use regex `-match` in a Where-Object clause

Comment: Correct @mclayton

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Preamble**

Per comments, to paraphrase your question to make sure I understand it, you have a file path which you've encoded by replacing `/` with `_` and   (space) with `%20`. You want to reverse the encoding to get back to the original file path, but your encoding is ambiguous:

- `_` in your encoded string could mean `/` or `_` in the original file path
- `%20` in your encoded string could mean `%20` or   (space) in the original file path

As a result, you need to generate all possible original values and then find the one that exists on your file system.

As an aside, this is why a lot of encodings have "escape sequences" so you know whether some part of the string is a literal or a token - e.g. in C# `var x = "line1\nline2\nline3";` - the `\n` unambiguously represents a new line character. If you wanted the string literal `\n` instead you'd have to escape the `\` like this: `var x = "line1\\nline2\\nline3";`. This way, there's only one original value that any encoded string can represent.

If you're able to, you might want to revisit your encoding rules by adding an escape character to make the encoded strings unambiguous.

**Answer**

I wrote an answer a while ago for a different question about transliterating words with Cyrillic characters into Latin characters that you could repurpose - see [variable transliteration (powershell)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63586565/3156906).

All you need to do with that answer is change the lookup table like this:

```
function ConvertTo-DecodedPath
{
    param(
        [string] $InputString
    )

    $lookups = [ordered] @{
        # single character substitutions
        # (we need to use the [char] cast to force case sensitivity for keys)
        [char] "_" = @( "_", "/" )
        # multi-character substitutions
        [string] "%20" = @( "%20", " " )
    }

    # if the input is empty then there's no work to do,
    # so just return an empty string
    if( [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($InputString) )
    {
        return [string]::Empty;
    }

    # find all the lookups that can be applied at the start of the string
    $keys = @( $lookups.Keys | where-object { $InputString.StartsWith($_) } );

    # if there are no lookups found at the start of the string we'll keep
    # the first character as-is and prefix it to all the transliterations
    # for the remainder of the string
    if( $keys.Length -eq 0 )
    {
        $results = @();
        $head    = $InputString[0];
        $rest    = $InputString.Substring(1);
        $tails   = ConvertTo-DecodedPath -InputString $rest;
        foreach( $tail in $tails )
        {
            $results += $head + $tail;
        }
        return $results;
    }

    # if we found any lookups at the start of the string we need to "multiply"
    # them with all the transliterations for the remainder of the string
    $results = @();
    foreach( $key in $keys )
    {
        if( $InputString.StartsWith($key) )
        {
            $heads = $lookups[$key];
            $rest  = $InputString.Substring(([string] $key).Length);
            $tails = ConvertTo-DecodedPath -InputString $rest;
            foreach( $head in $heads )
            {
                foreach( $tail in $tails )
                {
                    $results += $head + $tail;
                }
            }

        }
    }

    return $results;

}
```

**Example**

Here's an example based on your sample string. Note the values are different to the ones you've listed, but I think your list might be wrong because I can't see how `mail_sp_sp.sql` could become any of the strings you've given that end with `sql.sql` :-).

```
PS> ConvertTo-DecodedPath "mail_sp_sp.sql"
mail_sp_sp.sql
mail_sp/sp.sql
mail/sp_sp.sql
mail/sp/sp.sql
```

**Question**

What happens next if more than one of the decoded paths exists?

Comment: I added the function
I don't understand your answer. Regarding your question only one path could be true
I need to check each one of the combination in order to check if this file is exist like
if ($fileExist)
{ Write-Host "TFS file existance is: [$fileExist] by path [$filePathInTfs]" }
I will be happy if you can tell me if my script is correct while there is only one '_' as in the first eample

Comment: mail_sp_sp.sql?
It was only for example while there are many '_'

Comment: Maybe I need to run in a loop on your results? and check if one of them true?

Comment: I tried to run the function on a string 
ConvertTo-DecodedPath AD%20mail_sp.sql 
I got 4 results instead of 2. What should I need to change in order to get 2?
here is what I got:
AD%20mail_sp.sql
AD%20mail/sp.sql
AD mail_sp.sql
AD mail/sp.sql

%20 is always a space so I don't expect to 4 results. It should be only:

AD mail_sp.sql
AD mail/sp.sql

Comment: Regarding this %20 in your encoded string could mean %20 or   (space) in the original file path , the only option  here is to leave it as %20, can you change the function for me please?

Comment: Maybe the solution is run in a loop for results and break the loop once I found an exists file , in case there is no match it will be false, am I right? Just need to fix the issue with the %20

Comment: @bandit - the code above just generates to possible file names for a given encoded string - you can loop through those and call your ```CheckFileExistsTfs``` for each value until you find one that exists.

Comment: @bandit - you just need to change the bit that starts ```  $lookups =``` if you want different decoding  mappings applied.

Comment: Thanks should I need to remove the “  “ from string] "%20" = @( "%20", " " )? I’m not sure I understand

Comment: Don’t understand lookup= ``` what does it mean? Maybe you can mark what should be changed in the script. Thanks again

Comment: What should I need to change in order to get only 2 results for AD%20mail_sp.sql while %20 is always a space, please help

Comment: The $lookups variable controls the substitutions - if you don’t want one to happen, just remove it from the array.

Comment: Sorry but I think you didn’t understand me, I want the combination only for the ‘_’ but need to replace the %20 with a space but he don’t need to percipients in the combination. Means that your function should return only 2 combinations instead of 4, are you understand my needs? Really need your help to solve it, can you tell me exactly what need to change please ❤️

Comment: @bandit Can you add a specific example of what you mean into your question.

Comment: I add Additional example
The %20 should not be affected from you function. Only permutation of '_'

Comment: Now its more clear? @mclayton

Comment: Ok, so you need to change the lookup table - it currently maps “%20” to “%20” *and* “ “ (space) - you need to map it to just “ “ (space)